# What USEFUL bitwise operator code tricks should a developer know about?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bit

I must say I have never had cause to use bitwise operators, but I am sure there are some operations that I have performed that would have been more efficiently done with them. How have "shifting" and "OR-ing" helped you solve a problem more efficiently?

Comment: Would you mind to change your accepted answer to choose CS's answer?

Comment: @Xam - CS's answer came in almost 4 yrs after Martin's and it was instructive to me at the time I needed it. So on principle I won't change it, but CS and Mohasin both benefit from the upvotes that make their answers more popular than Martin's.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See the famous [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)
Most of the multiply/divide ones are unnecessary - the compiler will do that automatically and you will just confuse people.

But there are a bunch of, 'check/set/toggle bit N' type hacks that are very useful if you work with hardware or communications protocols.

Answer (score 158):

### Using bitwise operations on strings (characters)

Convert letter to **lowercase**:

- **`OR`** by space => `(x | ' ')`
- Result is always lowercase even if letter is already lowercase
- eg. `('a' | ' ') => 'a'` ; `('A' | ' ') => 'a'`

Convert letter to **uppercase**:

- **`AND`** by underline => `(x & '_')`
- Result is always uppercase even if letter is already uppercase
- eg. `('a' & '_') => 'A'` ; `('A' & '_') => 'A'`

**Invert** letter's case:

- **`XOR`** by space => `(x ^ ' ')`
- eg. `('a' ^ ' ') => 'A'` ; `('A' ^ ' ') => 'a'`

Letter's **position** in alphabet:

- **`AND`** by `chr(31)`/`binary('11111')`/(`hex('1F')` => `(x & "\x1F")`
- Result is in 1..26 range, letter case is not important
- eg. `('a' & "\x1F") => 1` ; `('B' & "\x1F") => 2`

Get letter's **position** in alphabet (for **Uppercase** letters only):

- **`AND`** by `?` => `(x & '?')` *or* **`XOR`** by `@`  => `(x ^ '@')`
- eg. `('C' & '?') => 3` ; `('Z' ^ '@') => 26`

Get letter's **position** in alphabet (for **lowercase** letters only):

- **`XOR`** by backtick/`chr(96)`/`binary('1100000')`/`hex('60')`  => `` (x ^ '`') ``
- eg. `` ('d' ^ '`') => 4 `` ; `` ('x' ^ '`') => 25 ``

*Note: using anything other than the english letters will produce garbage results*

Comment: How did you know i would be interested .... :)

Comment: @Ka: Does this works in javascript too? I tried these in `firebug's console` but I always got `0`.

Comment: @Razort4x it works in JS via [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). eg. `String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(0) & 95);`

Answer (score 72):

---

- Bitwise operations on integers(int)

---

**Get the maximum integer**

```
int maxInt = ~(1 << 31);
int maxInt = (1 << 31) - 1;
int maxInt = (1 << -1) - 1;
```

**Get the minimum integer**

```
int minInt = 1 << 31;
int minInt = 1 << -1;
```

**Get the  maximum long**

```
long maxLong = ((long)1 << 127) - 1;
```

**Multiplied by 2**

```
n << 1; // n*2
```

**Divided by 2**

```
n >> 1; // n/2
```

**Multiplied by the m-th power of 2**

```
n << m; // (3<<5) ==>3 * 2^5 ==> 96
```

**Divided by the m-th power of 2**

```
n >> m; // (20>>2) ==>(20/( 2^2) ==> 5
```

**Check odd number**

```
(n & 1) == 1;
```

**Exchange two values**

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

**Get absolute value**

```
(n ^ (n >> 31)) - (n >> 31);
```

**Get the max of two values**

```
b & ((a-b) >> 31) | a & (~(a-b) >> 31);
```

**Get the min of two values**

```
a & ((a-b) >> 31) | b & (~(a-b) >> 31);
```

**Check whether both have the same sign**

```
(x ^ y) >= 0;
```

**Calculate 2^n**

```
2 << (n-1);
```

**Whether is factorial of 2**

```
n > 0 ? (n & (n - 1)) == 0 : false;
```

**Modulo 2^n against m**

```
m & (n - 1);
```

**Get the average**

```
(x + y) >> 1;
((x ^ y) >> 1) + (x & y);
```

**Get the m-th bit of n (from low to high)**

```
(n >> (m-1)) & 1;
```

**Set the m-th bit of n to 0 (from low to high)**

```
n & ~(1 << (m-1));
```

**n + 1**

```
-~n
```

**n - 1**

```
~-n
```

**Get the contrast number**

```
~n + 1;
(n ^ -1) + 1;
```

**if (x==a) x=b; if (x==b) x=a;**

```
x = a ^ b ^ x;
```

Comment: Math.floor() === x >> 0 and Math.ceil() === y | 1 as well

Comment: From what I know, Bitwise operators are for integers and characters only and not for real valued types. You use Math.floor or Math.ceil with real valued numbers not integers.

Comment: what's the point of doing `if (x==a) x=b; if (x==b) x=a;`? it's just equivalent to `if (x == b) x = a;`. And the term for *contrast number* is the negated value or the two's complement, which could be easier done with `-n`

Comment: @phuclv I think these operations are very useful when you are doing operations in low-level languages. Instead of writing complex 'if-else' and branching logic in low-level language, it becomes easy to implement the logic this way.

Comment: @BraveNinja there's no complex if-else here. Only a single compare then jump is needed, or no jump at all if the architecture has conditional move. Moreover it's not quite a *useful* trick since it may actually be slower than normal assignments due to dependencies

Answer (score 15):

There's only three that I've ever used with any frequency:

1. Set a bit:
   `a |= 1 << bit;`
2. Clear a bit:
   `a &= ~(1 << bit);`
3. Test that a bit is set:
   `a & (1 << bit);`

Answer (score 10):

[Matters Computational: Ideas, Algorithms, Source Code, by Jorg Arndt (PDF)](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf). This book contains tons of stuff, I found it via a link at http://www.hackersdelight.org/

> Average without overflow
>
> A routine for the computation of the average (x + y)/2 of two
>   arguments x and y is
>
> ```
> static inline ulong average(ulong x, ulong y)
> // Return floor( (x+y)/2 )
> // Use: x+y == ((x&y)<<1) + (x^y)
> // that is: sum == carries + sum_without_carries
> {
>     return (x & y) + ((x ^ y) >> 1);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the book Link !

Answer (score 2):

1) Divide/Multiply by a power of 2

`foo >>= x;` (divide by power of 2)

`foo <<= x;` (multiply by power of 2)

2) Swap

```
x ^= y;
y = x ^ y;
x ^= y;
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to see benchmarks demonstrating whether those are actually faster than the normal way on modern compilers.

Comment: I'd be pretty confident the shift is faster. The swap is more about not needing additional memory than being faster.

Comment: @Taylor: Most modern compilers will use a shift when it's the fastest way, without you having to manually code it.

Answer (score 2):

You can compress data, e.g. a collection of integers:

- See which integer values appear more frequently in the collection
- [Use short bit-sequences to represent the values which appear more frequently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) (and longer bit-sequences to represent the values which appear less frequently)
- Concatenate the bits-sequences: so for example, the first 3 bits in the resulting bit stream might represent one integer, then the next 9 bits another integer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used bitwise operators to efficiently implement distance calculations for [bitstrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array). In my application bitstrings were used to represent positions in a discretised space (an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), if you're interested, encoded with [Morton ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_(curve))). The distance calculations were needed to know whether points on the grid fell within a particular radius.

Answer (score 1):

Counting set bits, finding lowest/highest set bit, finding nth-from-top/bottom set bit and others can be useful, and it's worth looking at the [bit-twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) site.

That said, this kind of thing isn't day-to-day important. Useful to have a library, but even then the most common uses are indirect (e.g. using a bitset container). Also, ideally, these would be standard library functions - a lot of them are better handled using specialise CPU instructions on some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

While multiplying/dividing by shifting seems nifty, the only thing I needed once in a while was compressing booleans into bits. For that you need bitwise AND/OR, and probably bit shifting/inversion.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a function to round numbers to the next highest power of two, so I visited the Bit Twiddling website that's been brought up several times and came up with this:

```
i--;
i |= i >> 1;
i |= i >> 2;
i |= i >> 4;
i |= i >> 8;
i |= i >> 16;
i++;
```

I use it on a `size_t` type. It probably won't play well on signed types. If you're worried about portability to platforms with different sized types, sprinkle your code with `#if SIZE_MAX >= (number)` directives in appropriate places.