# Bit-wise operation tricks

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What USEFUL bitwise operator code tricks should a developer know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533131/what-useful-bitwise-operator-code-tricks-should-a-developer-know-about)

Hi,

What are some neat tricks with using bit-wise operations.  I know that unless you're programming in C you won't have much encounters with operating on bit level.  Nonetheless, there are some neat tricks that you can apply in even higher level languages.  Here are a few that I already know.

1. [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_mask): Can hold a collection of boolean values
2. [XOR Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap): Swap 2 values in place without a third variable
3. XOR Linked List: Create a doubly linked list with each node only hold one address value

What are some others?

Comment: Actually bitmasks can be useful in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find whether a number is odd or not

```
(number & 1)
```

Comment: Which doesn't work for one's complement :-)

Comment: Oh who uses one's compliment =) (thank you google, I had no idea wtw)

Comment: Actually, I don't know anyone that _uses_ it, but the standard allows for it (as well as sign/magnitude) on top of two's complement. You can simply state that `number` is unsigned and you've fixed the problem (a la the answer from david van brink).

Comment: ahhhh nice, I'll do that now, uint32 standard enough?